# При авторизации через Google oAuth2 возникает ошибка "Call to a member function setAccessToken() on null"

Tags: php, oauth2

Делаю авторизацию на сайте через Google oAuth2. Код страницы авторизации **redirect.php**:

```
<?php

// Подключаем библиотеку для работы с API Google
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

session_start(); // Токен будем хранить в сессии

// Параметры приложения

// ID приложения
define('GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID', '1088086139046-lfr8h0dbk7rr9olb1tsgbtvtr31fir81.apps.googleusercontent.com');
// Secret приложения
define('GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET', 'XEc2_PKUb2gpbvBsimATmB9d');
// Адрес, на который будет переадресован пользователь после прохождения авторизации
define('GOOGLE_CLIENT_REDIRECT_URL', 'https://mhelper.ru/redirect.php');

// Области, к которым будет запрошен доступ
// Подробнее https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes
define( 'SCOPES', implode( ' ', [
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me'
] ) );

// Инициализация Google Client
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId( GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID );
$client->setClientSecret( GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET );
$client->setRedirectUri( GOOGLE_CLIENT_REDIRECT_URL );
$client->setScopes( SCOPES );
$client->setAccessType( 'offline' );
$client->setApprovalPrompt('force');

// Выводим на экран ссылку для открытия окна диалога авторизации
echo '<a href="' .  $client->createAuthUrl() . '">Авторизация через Google</a>';

if ( isset( $_GET['code'] ) ) {

    $response = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode( $_GET['code'] );

    // Если при получении токена произошла ошибка
    if (isset($response['error'])) {
        throw new Exception('При получении токена произошла ошибка. Error: ' . $response['error'] . '. Error description: ' . $response['error_description']);
    }

    $accessToken = $response['access_token']; // access токен
    $expiresIn = $response['expires_in']; // истекает через 3600 (сек.) (1 час)
    $refreshToken = $response['refresh_token']; // refresh токен - используется для обновления access токена
    $scope = $response['scope']; // области, к которым был получен доступ
    $tokenType = $response['token_type']; // тип токена
    $idToken = $response['id_token']; // id токена
    $created = $response['created']; // время создания токена 1537170421

    // Сохраняем токен в сессии
    $_SESSION['token'] = json_encode($response);
    echo $_SESSION['token'];
    echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;URL=/index.php">';
}

?>
```

После авторизации идет редирект на страницу **index.php**:

```
<?php

    require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

    session_start();

    // Извлекаем токен из сессии
    $accessToken = $_SESSION['token'];
    $client->setAccessToken( $accessToken );

    // Если время жизни токена истекло, обновляем его
    if ( $client->isAccessTokenExpired() ) {

        // При обновлении токена refresh токен отсутствует
        // Поэтому сохраняем refresh токен в отдельную переменную
        $refreshTokenSaved = $client->getRefreshToken();

        // Обновляем токен
        $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken( $client->getRefreshToken() );

        // Создаём новую переменную, в которую помещаем новый обновлённый токен
        $accessTokenUpdated = $client->getAccessToken();

        // Добавляем в эту переменную старый refresh токен
        $accessTokenUpdated['refresh_token'] = $refreshTokenSaved;

        // Сохраняем в сессии новый токен и старый refresh токен
        $_SESSION['token'] = json_encode($accessTokenUpdated);

        // Устанавливаем новый токен
        $client->setAccessToken($accessTokenUpdated);
    }

    // Получаем информацию о пользователе
    $oauth2 = new Google_Service_Oauth2($client);
    $userInfo = $oauth2->userinfo->get();

    $userInfo->email; // Email
    $userInfo->gender; // Пол (male)
    $userInfo->givenName; // Имя (Alex)
    $userInfo->familyName; // Фамилия (Codd)
    $userInfo->name; // Полное имя (Alex Codd)
    $userInfo->id; // ID
    $userInfo->link; // Ссылка на профиль в google plus
    $userInfo->picture; // Ссылка на фотографию

    ?>
```

При редиректе на индексную страницу возникает ошибка

> Nov 29 06:32:48 grace apache_error: mhelper.ru [Fri Nov 29 06:32:48
>   2019] [error] [pid 5962] sapi_apache2.c(325): [client
>   5.18.204.134:57674] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function setAccessToken() on null in
>   /home/p/pavloff/mhelper/public_html/index.php on line 9

Comment: А где у вас $client инициализируется в index.php?

Comment: Клиент инициализирауется в redirect-php для получения токена, а токен хранится в сессии.

Comment: Переменная $client у вас не инициализирована в index.php, из-за этого и выводится ошибка.